# Grab order details in hook woocommerce_checkout_order_processed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'send_order_fax');

function send_order_fax($order_id) {
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    die();
}
```

I want to grab the order id or order details when this hooks fire so that i can generate a fax. But it is only sending the form data. How can i get the order id so that i can fetch other things via functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get order details using following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'send_order_fax');

function send_order_fax($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    print_r($items);
    die();
}
```

Comment: nice , what other things i can grab ?

Comment: what you want to get?

Comment: user details, shipping details, payment method etc.

Comment: `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` will fail to work in child theme `functions.php` file, it will always return empty because the order was already processed and the session was wiped out. You have to use `get_post_meta($orderId)` for that.

Answer (score 1):

in reply to this:

> nice , what other things i can grab ? –  Raheel Khan

if you use var_dump( $order );
you will see all the information the object is holding.

**Edit:**

payment method:

```
get_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', true )
```

Comment: Yes i used xdebug for that but the orders object is giving top level details like custom id order id etc. Like the above answer `$items = $order->get_items();` i guess there are more helper functions

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html this is what i was asking