# Delete order() doesn't work. Woocommerce, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a plugin for delete the `Woocommerce order` when the user doesn't have enough point. But the delete `wp_delete_post();` is not work.

```
function delete_order($order)
{
     global $post; 
     $order_id = absint( get_query_var( 'order-pay' ) );

     //If the user do not have enough point
     if(get_user_bonus_point() < (int)$order->get_total())
     $post->wp_delete_post($order_id,true);
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'delete_order', 10, 1);
```

But after I place the order, the order didn't delete. But other functions are work when place order.

Thanks

Comment: is it going in **if** condition ?

Comment: Ys. The condition is working. I use `echo` to check it.

Comment: <?php wc_delete_order_item( $order_id ); ?> Try this

Comment: Are you getting **order id**?

Comment: I am trying to get the order id, I think that does not work.

Comment: Yes because I guess order is yet to be added in database table and hence you are not getting order id ..check the hook you are using once **woocommerce_checkout_order_processed**

Comment: Check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714691/grab-order-details-in-hook-woocommerce-checkout-order-processed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
function delete_order($order_id)
{
     global $post; 
     $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
     //If the user do not have enough point
     if(get_user_bonus_point() < (int)$order->get_total())
     $post->wp_delete_post($order_id,true);
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'delete_order', 10, 1);
```